# Labelling the same blob from frame to frame in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, imaging, matlab-cvst

I am new to image processing in `MATLAB`. So what I have to do is to label blobs on an image.
So the setup is basically markers on a person that are pickup by a camera. The image from the camera needs to be processed in `MATLAB`.

So the data I am getting from the camera are frames. Using region props and some other image processing algorithms, I changed the markers into blobs on the body. I am able to label each blobs (markers) with numbers 1 to 4 using `bwlabel`.

Now the problem I am having is that, when I move onto the next frame, depending on the position of the person at that time, `bwlabel` would label for instance `blob#2` in the previous frame as `blob#3` in the current frame.

So basically, what I am saying is the labels that are applied in each frame changes.

I want to keep the same labels throughout the whole number of frames.

Anyone has any idea on how this can be done?

Thank you so much.

Comment: In general you're looking for feature tracking. But depending on your particular case there may be shortcuts. Can you post a couple of sample images?

Comment: You are trying to perform "tracking" it sounds like you would benefit from an general introduction to the topic - try watching the second video lecture on this page from my computer vision class, it's 45 min long and has matlab code. http://personal.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Personal/J.Collomosse/teaching.php

Comment: @jcollomosse Thank you so much for the reply. I apologise for the late reply. I am trying to view the video from your website but unfortunately it does not seem to work. I really appreciate if you could reload the video. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Works for me. You need flash I'm afraid, otherwise email me and I'll sort something out

Answer (score 0):

You can track the blobs from frame to frame using the Kalman filter. If you have the Computer Vision System Toolbox, you can use the `vision.KalmanFilter` object to predict the location of a blob in the next frame, and the `assignDetectionsToTracks` function to match the predictions to detections. This [example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/motion-based-multiple-object-tracking.html) should give you a good starting point.

---